# Unable to find palindrome strings using Python

Tags: python

I have this code to check if a string is a palindrome, written in Python.

```
s=input()
for i,j in reversed(s),range(0,len(s)):
    if (i == s[j]):
        continue
    else:
        break
if (j == len(s)-1):
    print('Yes')
else:
    print('No')
```

I begin by traversing the variable 's' in reversed order and checking if it is the same as the original variable. If it is, the loop continues; else, exits.
At the end, I check the value of the loop variable 'i'. If it is equal to the length of the string, I conclude that 's' is a palindrome; else, it's not.
However, I get an error on the second line -

```
for i,j in reversed(s),range(0,len(s)):
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I don't understand what's wrong!

Comment: give some example string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ZIP the two iterables together. Try

```
for i,j in zip(reversed(s),range(0,len(s))):
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is most compact form for solution.
Simply reverse the string and match with orignal

```
is_palindrome = lambda s: str(s) == str(s)[::-1]

>>> is_palindrome('abcba')
>>> True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# use enumerate
for j,i in enumerate(reversed(s)):
    if (i == s[j]):
        continue
    else:
        break
if (j == len(s)-1):
    print('Yes')
else:
    print('No')
```

This is another solution:

```
#s[::-1] reverses the string
print('Yes') if s==s[::-1] else print('No')
```

Answer (score 0):

Zohab's answer is the way I would do achieve what you're hoping to do, though it doesn't explain why you're getting that ValueError (and therefore you'll probably end up running into it again in the future).

What it looks like you're trying to do is align the reversed iterable "s" with a ranged iterable based on its length. The reason this is failing as-written is because the Python interpreter is reading your code (roughly) as:

```
for reference in [reversed(s),range(0,len(s))]:
    (i,j) = reference
```

So, with an input of "Hello World" it would basically run like this:

```
for reference in [reversed("Hello World"),range(0,len("Hello World"))]:
    ## First Iteration
    reference = "dlroW olleH"
    i =  reference[0] ## "d"
    j = reference[1]  ## "l"
    ValueError ## We don't have a variable to assign reference[2]/"r" to
```

Obviously, this is not what you wanted to do.

The solution to this exact error is, as TimGJ said, to use the zip() function, which will create a new object that pairs the characters of reversed(s) to the numbers of range(0,len(s)). This results in:

```
for i,j in (("d",0),("l",1),etc...):
    ## First iteration
    i = "d"
    j = 0
```

Which is what you wanted. However, zipping to a range like this is already covered by the enumerate() function, as Allen pointed out.

I will also note- purely for clarification- that range(n) is the same as range(0,n).